# Does 前提に mean "to require"?

Tags: words

I recently came across the expression `前提に`:

> feature1はfeature2と同じく各コンテンツに分類用の識別子を埋め込む機能ですが、統制を重視したユースケースを前提に設計されているため柔軟さに欠けます。
>   'feature1, just like feature2, is a way to embed classification into content, but it is designed for rigidity-focussed use cases, losing in flexibility.'

I think it means "to require", but I am very unsure, could someone confirm/infirm this?

Comment: Haha, I guess I'm not the only StackOverflow user here :)

Comment: actually pretty much all stackexchange users are stackoverflow users in my experiance it's hard to find a stackexchange site with no significant amount of programming users.

Comment: @Ken Li I was actually listening to a StackOverflow podcast, where either Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood were saying how a large amount of SE users are now "civilians", or people who weren't SO users first. I forget the exact fraction, but it was close to half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

前提 has a meaning of on the assumption that, or on the premise of.

In your case its meaning is closer to

> it is designed under the assumption of
>   rigid focused use cases.

or

> Designed with rigid focused use cases in mind.

Another example from a site for something completely different:

> 彼氏がいる**前提**で、彼氏の有無を確認する7つのフレーズ

Which means

> **On the assumption** that there is a boyfriend, the 7 ways of confirming if there's a boyfriend.

Answer (score 3):

前途 is "premise" and 設計 is "architected" (or in this context, "designed"). Xを前提に設計された therefore means "designed under the premise of X".

By the way, I would translate your sentence slightly differently:

> feature1はfeature2と同じく各コンテンツに分類用の識別子を埋め込む機能ですが、統制を重視したユースケースを前提に設計されているため柔軟さに欠けます。
>
> Feature1, like feature2, is a way to embed into content discriminatory flags for classification. However, since they were designed under the premise of unified (homogeneous) usage cases, they lack flexibility.

Mostly the same as your translation, except for "designed for rigidity-focused use cases" :)

Answer (score 0):

設計する is "to design" and 前提 could be interpreted as, say, "condition" or something that was proposed. So you could read it as "something was designed for the purposes of so-and-so".

I guess it's possible to read it as something related to requirements as you're trying to satisfy some constraint but I don't think I've ever seen 設計する used as "to require" anyway.